# Is updating Ubuntu from Chinese servers safe?

Tags: updates

Ubuntu lets you set your preferred distro download source location. Can one assume that the Chinese(1) sources listed are unmolested copies? Does Ubuntu do its own checksum validation on these distros? Can I safely select from any location in the list?

(1) - or whatever likely government you prefer, for the sake of discussion

Comment: I'm indirectly asking about the security of update patches located on officially recognized Ubuntu servers. You may take issue with the geographic area mentioned, but I think the core idea is not inappropriate.

Comment: No surprise here ! I'd suggest you ask your question on a forum like slashdot. The core idea is not inappropriate, indeed, but AU has a different bent.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch! Your query is culturally sensitive and has (almost) nothing to do with Linux. Ditto for my answer.

From direct personal and extensive experience in Asia and in particular in China, my recommendation would be:

***Do not*** install new software or even update any software you may have installed in your box when traveling. Switch your automatic updates off during your time on the road in PRC as in a small number of other countries, sophisticated enough to open a back-door or perform zero-day exploits on a plain-vanilla system. That goes for **any OS**.

This is not daydreaming or gratuitous paranoia, I lived through all of that, installing a couple of Lx company wide systems in China.

I don't care that there might be hunky-dory checksums there to put you at ease. Be smart and don't become complacent, do it the hard way over encrypted VPN only AND check your checksums there as well.

If encrypted VPN is not your cup of baijiu and your box is portable, wait and install whatever you need AFTER you get back home, i.e. outside the Great Wall. Japan is fine, so is India. HongKong, Tibet and Mongolia are between "iffy" and "no-no". But that's a judgment call on my part. I never "worked" in those latter countries.

Is this not completely off-topic ?